# How does precedence apply on an expression with an assignment and a conditional?

Tags: ruby, operator-precedence

I have the following simple snippet:

```
var = 1 if false
```

I would expect this to evaluate as:

```
(var = 1) if false
```

so `var` would be undefined. However, `var` gets defined and receives a `nil` as its value.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby recognizes local variables during parsing. So, in your case, even thouogh it's not set to `1` (because the precedence of this expression is like you wrote), ruby knows that it's local variable and doesn't raise `NameError`.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby parser defines `var` when it sees it on the lefthand side of an expression (even though its inside of a conditional that doesn’t run). So `nil` looks an appropriate value.